# class.getResourceAsStream() not reading file and pointing to NULL

Tags: java, file-io

I have tried placing the json file in the source folder however I am unable to get the getResourceAsStream() to read the file I am directing it to.

```
boolean isFound = PredictionEngine.class.getResourceAsStream("client_secrets.json") != null;
System.out.println(isFound);
```

I am testing the file with the code above can you help me figure out why it is not finding the file.

Comment: Try with `/` at start of path.

Comment: _in the source folder_ Why did you put it there? How is the `String` you provided to `getResourceAsStream` related to that location?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If I am not mistaken that is commonly used practice. We are creating *source folders* to make sure its content will be added to generated JARs (at least it works in Eclipse). Later we can simply use `getResource("/path/to/resource")`.

Comment: @Pshemo You're not mistaken. My intention is to have OP clarify their question with more details of why they did what they did.

Comment: Than yes, I misunderstood your intentions. Usually when I see "why you did this?" I understand it as "that was wrong way of doing it" instead of "it was OK, but you need to think about it farther".

Comment: I tried adding a forward slash to the file name and still is not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because client_secrets.json file might not be in your class path. Check  if  client_secrets.json is present your target folder (where classes get generated)  basically on \target\classes

Comment: I don't know exactly how to check this could you explain what I need to look for thanks